# Thymeleaf and Springboot project - tag names

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a Springboot & Thymeleaf project that is generating the same "names" on my person inputs.

The controller looks like:

```
    @GetMapping("/newEpisode")
public String episodeForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("episode", new Episode());
    List<Country> countries = countryRepository.findAll();
    Set<String> roles = new HashSet<>();
    roles.add("Admin");
    model.addAttribute("primaryPerson1",new EpisodePerson());
    model.addAttribute("primaryPerson2",new EpisodePerson());
    model.addAttribute("roles", roles);
    model.addAttribute("countries", countries);
    return "episode";
}
```

Some of my HTML looks like:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control person surname" style="text-transform: uppercase" data-property="surname" placeholder="SURNAME" th:field="${primaryPerson1.person.surname}"/>
```

But the generated name in the HTML for this tag is not unique:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control person surname" style="text-transform: uppercase" data-property="surname" id="surname1" placeholder="SURNAME" name="person.surname" value="">
```

Why are all the person tags in the html sharing the same name for example I have two :

```
name="person.surname"
```

Answer (score 1):

You've misused the `th:field` attribute.

Its aim is to bind your input with a property in the form-backing bean. So you should either create separate forms for each object and use it in following manner:

```
<!-- Irrelevant attributes omitted -->
<form th:object="${primaryPerson1}">
    <input th:field="*{person.surname}"/>
</form>
```

...or create a form-backing bean, which would combine both of your objects, e.g.:

```
public class EpisodeFormBean {

    private List<EpisodePerson> episodePersons;

    //getter and setter omitted
}
```

...then add it to a model in your `episodeForm` method...

```
EpisodeFormBean episodeFormBean = new EpisodeFormBean();
episodeFormBean.setEpisodePersons(Arrays.asList(new EpisodePerson(), new EpisodePerson()));
model.addAttribute("episodeFormBean", episodeFormBean);
```

...and use it in your template as follow:

```
<!-- Irrelevant attributes omitted -->
<form th:object="${episodeFormBean}">
    <input th:field="*{episodePersons[0].person.surname}"/>
    <input th:field="*{episodePersons[1].person.surname}"/>
</form>
```

In the second solution generated names would be unique. I think it's more suitable for your needs.

You should check out [Tutorial: Thymeleaf + Spring](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#inputs) as there it is well explained. Especially you should notice a phrase:

> Values for `th:field` attributes must be selection expressions (`*{...}`),
>   which makes sense given the fact that they will be evaluated on the
>   form-backing bean and not on the context variables (or model
>   attributes in Spring MVC jargon).